# Срабатывание таймера javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, у меня два вопроса.
Вот код:

```
if(timeoutID1)clearTimeout(timeoutID1);
timeoutID1 = setTimeout(searchExecutor(), 3000);
```

первый вопрос: почему первая строка вызывает ошибку?
второй вопрос: если первую строку закомментировать, почему таймер срабатывает сразу же и вызывает функцию `searchExecutor()` , почему? как этого избежать, она должна срабатывать через 3 секунды.
Спасибо.

Comment: 1. Таймер не определен. 2. Скобки не нужны.

Comment: как сделать проверку определен ли таймер? Разве конструкция if(timeoutID1) не делает этого?

Comment: Ну вы же не указали, что за ошибку получаете. Видимо мой хрустальный шар немного поломался :)

Comment: Ну и потом, попытка обращения _к необъявленной переменной_  должна вызывать (и вызывает) ошибку ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.

> почему первая строка вызывает ошибку?

В строке

```
if(timeoutID1)clearTimeout(timeoutID1); // ReferenceError: timeoutID1 is not defined
```

вы пытаетесь использовать не инициализированную переменную `timeoutID1` и это вызывает ошибку. Таймеры тут не причем. Совсем. Та же ошибка проявляется и в коде без использования функций работы с таймерами:

```
if(timeoutID1) 'foo'; // ReferenceError: timeoutID1 is not defined
```

Решение проблемы тривиально: определяйте переменные перед их использованием:

```
var timeoutID1;
if(timeoutID1)clearTimeout(timeoutID1);
```

Далее

> почему таймер срабатывает сразу же и вызывает функцию searchExecutor() , почему?

Потому, что интерпретатор JavaScript делает **ровно то** что вы говорите ему делать. Вот в этой строке:

```
timeoutID1 = setTimeout(searchExecutor(), 3000);
```

вы приказываете интерпретатору выполнить **результат выполнения** функции `searchExecutor()` через 3000 миллисекунд (да, функции в JS могут возвращать другие функции). Решение, как и всегда, тривиально - используйте саму функцию, а не результат ее выполнения:

```
timeoutID1 = setTimeout(searchExecutor, 3000);
```

---

**TL;DR:**

1. Таймер не определен.
2. Скобки не нужны.